# Constructor Template

Tags: c++, templates, enums, constructor

I have a class with several constructors. According to a parameter which is passed via argv to main() I would like to switch between the different constructors. The following simplified example works fine in the case where "obj" is changed to class and I use e.g. obj1->int and obj2->double. But what do I have to change to make the following code run using enum?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

enum obj{obj1,obj2};

template <obj T>
class A
{
public:
  A(T);

private:
  T t_;
};

template<obj T>
A<T>::A(T )
{}

template<>
A<obj1>::A(obj1 t):t_(t) {cout<<"case 1"<< endl;}

template<>
A<obj2>::A(obj2 t):t_(t) {cout<<"case 2"<< endl;}

int main()
{
    obj test=obj1;
    A<obj> a(test);
    return 1;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: It's clear that the code is wrong concerning type/value, but which mechanism can resemble such a switching of constructors?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  `obj1` and `obj2` are enum *values*, but you're trying to use them as *types*.

Comment: `template<obj T>` means you need to provide **an enum value**. `A<obj>` will not be compiled, because it is not a value, it is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is what you intended to do:

```
#include<iostream>

enum obj{obj1,obj2};

template<obj>
class A
{
public:
    A();

private:
    obj t_;
};

template<obj x>
A<x>::A() : t_(x){}

template<>
A<obj1>::A() : t_(obj1){ std::cout << "obj1\n"; }

template<>
A<obj2>::A() : t_(obj2){ std::cout << "obj1\n"; }

int main()
{
    const obj x = obj1; //  can only be used as the template argument below because it's a compile time constant
    A<x> a;

    return 0;
}
```

However this only works if you want to 'switch' on a compile time constant, and it sounds like you don't. You need to use a run time condition (`if`, `switch`, etc).

Comment: Now I see the problem, I cannot get around the const, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You have to specialize on types, not on values. If you know the value at compile-time, you could use `boost::mpl::int_` to do so. If you don't (like in your case), you'll have to live with plain old `if`.

Comment: The hint concerning boost::mpl::int_ is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching the problem wrong. Templates are instantiated at compile-time so you can't choose a specialization based on a value that is present at runtime. Aside from other mistakes in your code this solution won't work.

A common solution to this kind of problem (creating different objects based on a parameter) is the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). It means that you move the conditional constructing logic to a factory class and use virtual methods to avoid the need to write different code on the calling side (so essentially you make use of polymorphism).

Comment: A correction to my upper code would be the following one. But then the parameter-lists have to be equal.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

enum obj_type{obj1,obj2};

template<int N>
struct obj
{
};



template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
A(int, int);
    private:
            int a_;
     int b_;
     obj_type type;
};


template<>
A<obj<obj1> >::A(int a, int b):a_(a),b_(b)
{
cout<<"case 1"<<endl;
this->type=obj1;
}


template<>
A<obj<obj2> >::A(int a, int b):a_(a)
{
b_=0;
cout<<"case 2"<<endl;
this->type=obj2;
}



int main()
{

    A<obj<obj2> > a(1,2);
return 1;
}

Comment: sorry I won't decipher that. use an online code pasting (pastebin.com)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show me. As I said, the templates are instantiated at compile time. You can't choose a specialization at runtime. obj1 and obj2 are known at compile-time, you can't put a variable in place of the `int N` template paramter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
enum E
{
    A,
    B
};

template<E e>
struct A
{
};

template<>
struct A<E::A>
{
};

template<>
struct A<E::B>
{
};

int main()
{
    A<E::B> ab;
}
```